# How do I call information from more than one database and display it on a single page?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have information for my site broke down into multiple databases by categories. For example, my databases are Animals, Certificates, and Crafting. All of the databases have the same column names with the information I need to display. The columns are `Name`, `Img`, `Item_Code`, and `Length`. All of the tables also join a table called `Styles` with `Style_ID`.

How can I display the information from all of these tables in alphabetical order on a single page without actually having to create a "Master" database?

I don't know if it makes a difference, but I am using phpMyAdmin and a PHP site.

Comment: Do you want the information from `Styles` as well?

Comment: Yes, actually, I do for later.

Comment: To be clear, you actually have multiple *tables* in one database, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `UNION` query to fetch all the data from each table, adding an extra column to indicate the category if desired:

```
(SELECT  Name, Img, `Code`, Length, 'Animal' AS Category FROM Animals)
UNION
(SELECT  Name, Img, `Code`, Length, 'Certificate' AS Category FROM Certificates)
UNION
(SELECT  Name, Img, `Code`, Length, 'Crafting' AS Category FROM Crafting)
ORDER BY Name
```

If you also want to include the information from `Styles`, use the above query as a derived table (adding the `Style_ID` column) and `JOIN` that to `Styles` (I've assumed the appropriate column in `Styles` is `ID`):

```
SELECT *
FROM ((SELECT  Name, Img, `Code`, Length, 'Animal' AS Category, Style_ID FROM Animals)
     UNION
     (SELECT  Name, Img, `Code`, Length, 'Certificate', Style_ID FROM Certificates)
     UNION
     (SELECT  Name, Img, `Code`, Length, 'Crafting', Style_ID FROM Crafting)) d
JOIN Styles s ON s.ID = d.Style_ID
ORDER BY Name
```

Comment: I had to fix the column called Code to make it Item_Code since "Code" was showing as a query word for something. But when I put in your first one in with the updated name it came back with this error: #1271 - Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'

Comment: To fix the issue with `Code`, surround it in backticks. See my edit

Comment: The error probably means you have different collations in your tables on one of the fields. Are they all the same? If so, you may just need to collate the `Category` field the same way.

Comment: @JoAnnMoak can you give me more info (on the collations) to help you solve this?

Comment: Ok, I don't need the categories, this is more or less just to make an index of everything on the site. As for the tables, they are all the same except each one has its own ID to it.The data is different of course, but the column names are what I said, Name, Img, Item_Code, Length, and Style_ID. Each database has its own ID as in Animals_ID, Certificates_ID, etc.

Comment: OK, I tried it again, but this time added the Select * From before your first code and this time I got this error: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias.

Comment: I finally found and fixed the issue. Took me a moment to figure out what you meant by collations. But when I looked closely at all of it, I found the crafting table had accidently been done differently.

Comment: After I fixed the parenthesis and moved the ORDER By part to the end, the second one works fine, but it has 2 extra columns of Style_ID that I don't need.

Comment: @JoAnnMoak glad you resolved the collation issue - sorry I wasn't more specific. And apologies for forgetting to move the `ORDER BY` clause in the second query. You can always change the `*` in the field list to include only the columns that you want from `Styles`

Comment: Styles only has 2 fields. Style_ID and the corresponding Style. Actually, the terms I used were Types_ID and Type, but same idea. That field basically told me where the item came from in the first place with a little more detail. For example it broke crafting down even further so that I knew if it was from the kitchen, kiln, or workshop.